# How to set informix Delimident for SpringBoot project?

Tags: spring-boot, informix

I am having issue with column name aliasing in Springboot project as informix converts column name to lowercase.

for example if I write a query : "Select my_name as "myName" from tablename" then "myName" gets converted to "myname" . Solution is to set delimident. Can anyone tell how to set delimident in application.yml file for a Springboot project.

Answer (score 1):

You can set DELIMIDENT in the database URL passed to the JDBC driver:

```
jdbc:informix-sqli://<HOST>:<PORT>/<DATABASE_NAME>:informixserver=<IBM Informix instance name>;user=<user_name>;password=<password>;DELIMIDENT=Y;
```

The URL format and properties are described here:

[IBM® Informix® JDBC Driver, Version 4.10, Format of database URLs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.jdbc_pg.doc/ids_jdbc_036.htm#ids_jdbc_036)

[Informix environment variables with the IBM Informix JDBC Driver](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.jdbc_pg.doc/ids_jdbc_040.htm#ids_jdbc_040)

Comment: already tried this solution, its not working for me in spring boot project .When I am writing my DB connection URL in "application.yml" file

Comment: Then the name of the table is reaching the JDBC driver already in lowercase. I have no experience with Springboot, but try to check which NamingStrategy your framework is using. Probably converting all table names to lowercase.